# Intersection and one to one

Tags: general-topology

Prove: A function $f:X\rightarrow Y$ is one to one if and only if $f(A\cap B) = f(A)\cap f(B)$, for all subsets $A$ and $B$ of $X$.

proof: Let $A,B\subset X$ be any two subsets of $X$. Also, let $f(A\cap B)\subset f(A)\cap f(B)$, and let $y\in f(A\cap B)$. Then, there exists $x\in A\cap B$ such that $f(x) = y$. $x\in A$ and $x\in B$. $f(x)\in f(A)$ and $f(x)\in f(B)$. $y\in A$ and $y\in B$. $f(y)\in f(B)$. $y\in f(A)\cap f(B)$. Now we need to show that $f$ is one to one:

$f(A)\cap f(B)\subset f(A\cap b)$. Because $y\in f(A)$ there exists $x_{1}\in A$ such that $f(x_{1}) = y$. Because $y\in f(B)$ there exists an $x_{2}\in B$ such that $f(x_{2}) = y$. Since $f(x_{1}) = y = f(x_{2})$, and $f$ is one to one, we have $x_{1} = x_{2}$. Therefore, $x_{1}\in B$, so, $x _{1}\in A\cap B$, $f(x_{1}) = f(A\cap B)$ and $y\in f(A\cap B)$.

Now, we need to show the converse, i.e. $f:X\rightarrow Y$ is one to one if and only if $f(A)\cap f(B) = f(A\cap B)$. Let, $f(A)\cap f(B)\subset f(A\cap B)$, and let $x\in f(A)\cap f(B)$. Then, there exists an $y\in A\cap B$ such that $f(y) = x$. $y\in A$ and $y\in B$. $f(y)\in f(A)$ and $f(y)\in f(B)$. $x\in A$ and $x\in B$. $f(x)\in f(A)$ and $f(x)\in f(B)$. $x\in f(A\cap B).

Now, we need to show that $f$ is one to one:

$f(A\cap B)\subset f(A)\cap f(B)$. Because $x\in f(A)$ there exists an $y_{1}\in A$ such that $f(y_{1}) = x$. Because $y\in f(B)$ there exists an $y_{2}\in B$ such that $f(y_{2}) = x$. Since $f(y_{1}) = x = f(y_{2})$, and $f$ is one to one we have $y_{1} = y_{2}$ therefore $y_{1}\in A$ and $y_{1}\in B$ so $f(y_{1}) = f(A)\cap f(B)$ and $x\in f(A)\cap f(B)$

I know this is long but I just want to make sure that I am right, let me know if there is a mistake in my reasoning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got a lot of halfway good ideas, and something wiht the general appearance of a proof, but it's not a proof. To be a proof, every sentence needs to be unambiguously true, and that truth must be justified with reasons. Sometimes it helps to write out two columns, one with "statements" and the other with "reasons" to make certain that you've done this justifying properly.

Your first step should be "Suppose that $A$ and $B$ are any two subsets of $X$, and that $f$ is $1-to-1$. We'll show that $f(A \cap B) = f(A) \cap f(B)$." Then there should be some proof steps.

Then you should say:

"Now suppose $f(A \cap B) = f(A) \cap f(B)$ for every pair of subsets $A$ and $B$, and that $x_1$ and $x_2$ are points of $X$ with $f(x_1) = f(x_2)$. We'll show that $x_1 = x_2$." The proof for this second half might well be done by constructing two subsets $A$ and $B$ for which the known statement "$f(A \cap B) = f(A) \cap f(B)$" tells you something about $x_1$ and $x_2$. Hint: Try something like $A = \{ x_1, x_2\}$ and $B = \emptyset$. That won't work, but it might give you some ideas.

As it stands, your first paragraph is just some rambling stuff. The second sentence, "Also, let $f(A\cap B)\subset f(A)\cap f(B)$..." doesn't really make sense: you don't need to LET that be true...it's always true, for any function. You might want to prove this to yourself before you start the rest of the proof.

The third sentence, "Then there exists an $x \in A$" is false: everything you've said up to now is true for $A = B = \emptyset$, but in this case, there is no $x \in A$. Ignoring that for the moment and moving on, the statements "$y \in A$ and $y \in B$" are both generally false: $y$ is in the set $Y$, which may be completely different from $X$. (For instance, $X$ might consist of all real numbers, and $Y$ consist of all cheese omelets.)

Here's a complete proof:

Suppose that $A$ and $B$ are any two subsets of $X$, and that $f$ is $1$-to-$1$. We'll show that $f(A \cap B) = f(A) \cap f(B)$.

First, $f(A \cap B) \subset f(A) $ and $f(A \cap B) \subset f(B)$ so 
$$
$f(A \cap B) \subset f(A) \cap f(B).
$$
We need only show the reverse inclusion, i.e., that every element of $f(A) \cap f(B)$ is also in $f(A \cap B)$. Suppose $u \in f(A) \cap f(B)$. Then there is an element $a \in A$ with $u = f(a)$ and an element $b \in B$ with $u = f(B)$.

Now $f(a) = f(b)$, and $f$ is assumed to be $1$-to-$1$, so $a = b$. Thus $a$ is in both $A$ and $B$, hence in $A \cap B$. So for an arbitrary element $u$ of $f(A) \cap f(B)$, we've shown an element $a$ of $A \cap B$ with $f(a) = u$. This concludes the first part of the proof.

Now suppose $f(A \cap B) = f(A) \cap f(B)$ for every pair of subsets $A$ and $B$, and that $x_1$ and $x_2$ are points of $X$ with $f(x_1) = f(x_2)$. Let's call $f(x_1)$ by the name $u$. We'll show that $x_1 = x_2$."

Let $A = \{ x_1 \}$ and $ B = \{ x_2 \}$. Then since 
$$
f(A \cap B) = f(A) \cap f(B)
$$
we have 
$$
f(A \cap B) = \{u \}  \cap \{ u\} = \{ u \}
$$
This clearly implies that $A \cap B$ is nonempty. Let $z$ be an element of $A \cap B$. Then $z $ is an element of $A$, hence $z = x_1$; similarly, $z$ is an element of $B$, hence $z = x_2$. Thus $x_1 = x_2$, and we are done.

Comment: Do you know where I can find a complete proof of this?

Comment: I have no idea. This seems like a random textbook exercise to teach you how to write proofs, not a theorem that anyone would be likely to actually use. But I could be mistaken -- do you have an application for it?

Comment: You are right it is just a random textbook exercise, but yea I was just wondering if there were was a full proof somewhere

Comment: Added to my answer.